# How to delete a cell in BigTable GCP using nodejs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have a row with a key 'XYZ' in which there is a column family name 'PQR', so how do i delete a cell with column qualifier 'abc' in it using nodejs,
Can someone help me with the **syntax or documentation** to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the following code:

```
const row = table.row('XYZ');

// Delete specific column within a family.
let cols = [
  'PQR:abc'
];

row
  .deleteCells(cols)
  .then(result => {
    const apiResponse = result[0];
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Handle the error.
  });
```

Check out the [NodeJS Bigtable API reference documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/index.html) for other similar questions. And here is the [deleteCells reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Row.html#deleteCells) if you'd like more information for this question.